# How to send user input to designated e-mail?

Tags: ios, swift, email, user-data

I am developing an iOS app targeting iOS 9 and above using Swift 3 and xCode 8.

I have a "Contact ViewController" which contains multiple forms where user enters its data to submit. Collected data also contains users' e-mail address. I am validating all the information that entered by the user correctly.

So, what I would like to do is my "send" button to send the user's all data to an e-mail address.

Is this possible without using Mail App or its interface? Do I need additional framework for such functionality?

I appreciate your time and sharing your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible secretly. You can't send an email from the users device via the Apple Mail app because the system will not allow that. You can prepare an email with all the data that opens and let the user send it to you by tapping "Send" in the NavigationBar. So yes, you would need another framework to do that.

But I would not use emails to do that. Just use a server you send the data to or a service like Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to send E-mails, and just pushing the data to a backend API is not enough:

This is not possible using built-in functionality, but you could leverage an external mail delivery service like Mailgun to send your mails. (From a security standpoint, this should be handled by a server and not by the app itself however.)